# How to search in multiple indexes with same field

Tags: splunk

I want to search in two indexes. I need to extract one field's value from the first index and search for it in the second index, and then I need the count. It's hard to write it down, sorry.

Soo.. something like.:

```
index=firstIndex someUniqueField=something | rex commonField=someregex |
```

And the other search:

```
index=secIndex someOtherUniqueField=something2 | commonfield= theRegexedStuff
```

And I want this to be in one query and get the count of it. Is it even possible?

One thing to add: 
The second search will usually have less results, since it is an error case. So actually I want a number as a result, where the first search's unique field is there AND for the common field there is a result in the second search AND in the second search the unique field is there. Ugh, cannot really explain it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this?

`(index=firstIndex someUniqueField=something) OR (index=secIndex someOtherUniqueField=something2) | rex commonField=someregex | commonfield= theRegexedStuff `

Answer (score 0):

If the first search returns fewer than 10,000 results then you can use a subsearch.  The first search goes into the subsearch because subsearches run first.

```
index=secIndex someOtherUniqueField=something2 
  [ search index=firstIndex someUniqueField=something 
  | rex commonField=someregex 
  | fields commonField 
  | format ]
```